# Hypothesis / significance tests to study correlated time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, binomial-distribution

Assume I have two time series, A(t) and B(t). I **do know** the exact signals in A(t). I want to find out when a known signal in A(t) is causing a signal in B(t).[image: Figure illustrating the time series]

- In case of pure noise the data in both is distributed around the mean (not necessarily Gaussian, as there is systematic noise even after pre-whitening/detrending).
- Any signal will increase in a time-dependent manner, peak, and decrease.
- A(t) can cause a signal in B(t), but will not always cause one.
- If it causes a signal, the impact is immediate (at lag 0).
- Both have independent (systematic) noise properties.
- If there is no signal in A(t) there is no signal in B(t) expected
  (however there might be systematic noise that looks similar).

My current analyses:

1. First, I look at the data from the time series point-of-view, and perform auto-correlation, cross-correlation and rolling correlation analyses. I use the signal-to-noise ratio in e.g. the cross-correlation as a handle on 'significance' (not in a statistical sense).
2. Second, I try to explore other statistical options. Assume I do know when in time the signal in A(t) starts and ends. I extract the time points in B(t) at these times as a seperate sample, B*.

   - I perform a T-test to see whether B* data is distributed around the mean of B(t).
   - I perform a binominal test to see whether B* data is randomly distributed around the mean, or biased in any direction.

   I.e. if B* data contains a signal, both tests will reject the Null Hypotheses. However, this somewhat decreases my signal-to-noise ratio, as it includes the ramping parts of the signal, which are not that far off the mean.

My questions are:

1. are any of these tests redundant?
2. how do I retrieve values of 'statistical significance' from the cross-correlation etc?
3. are there any other possibilities to analyse this data that I am not thinking of (either as time series or as seperate sample B*)?

Comment: In case you use Stata, how about using Impulse Respone?
http://blog.stata.com/2016/10/27/long-run-restrictions-in-a-structural-vector-autoregression/

Comment: Have you tried with permutation tests to find statistical signifiance or surrogate data? If you permute time points in B(t) you are building data with no temporal correlation with the previous A(t) signal, so you will obtain a certain value of (auto/cross)-correlation measure. If you repeat time-point permutation you will have a null-distribution of your measures and understand if your original signal B(t) have values of (auto/cross)-correlation greater than your permuted time series.